# Any advantage of using Google Cloud over VPS?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, vps

I've visited Google Cloud full day "training" and I still don't get if there is any REAL advantage in using it for my Laravel applications.
Currently I'm using a VPS server from local hosting provider, and I can deploy a laravel application in 5 ssh commands. In few minutes it becomes live.
I've searched through options on how to do it on GoogleCloud. All of them are for minimum 2 hours of tedious reading/clicking and none offers deploying straight from a git repository, thus no continuous integration.

Please help me understand what is the advantage of paying 5 times more and configuring 20 times longer in GoogleCloud versus VPS?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you try to achieve by deploying your Laravel app. If you expect little traffic and of a constant nature, you local hosting provider is fine. Do you expect your app to scale for millions of requests per second? Would you value resilience? In this case, you are better off doing a little extra effort and deploying in the cloud. You may gather more detail from the "Building Scalable and Resilient Web Applications on Google Cloud Platform" [online document](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps).

Comment: thank you @George. I figured out the difference between Google App Engine and Google Cloud Engine. I've tried cloning one of my websites into Google Cloud's Centos using same techniques that I'm used to and I got amazing speed. 0.6 sec vs 1.4 sec load time.
I'll think I'll hang on a bit while it's free, and then probably keep using it instead of my VPS for the sake of really amazing speed. Not only the speed for clients, but also for deployments. I think I'm getting what's it all about now.